# How do I get wireless to work on a Dell Mini 1018 with Realtek RTL 8188CE Network Adapter?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, realtek, lan

My Dell Mini 1018 used to work fine with Ubuntu 12.04 with no problems connecting with the wireless card.  Then I made the big mistake of attempting to disable WiFi by right-clicking on the wireless applet and un-checking "Enable Wireless."  Since then, I cannot get wireless working again.  The wireless applet reports that "wireless is disabled by hardware switch" but there is no hardware switch on this computer.  Issuing a rfkill list yields the following:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: yes
      Hard block:   yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: yes
```

I'm in way over my head, and my computer is now useless.  Help!!!

Comment: Does `rfkill unblock all` do anything?

Comment: do you have to go into your bios everytime ???

Answer (score 2):

Go into BIOS and select restore from defaults. That has worked for me every time.
The rfkill command does nothing.